# JavaMail API not working on Mobile Data but fine on Wifi

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm in quite weird situation right now. For full code, here you can see: http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/

I'm using this code for sending email purposes. But the problem is ahead. I have 100% success rate while sending mail using this method on WIFI. But when I use Mobile Data (4G), I have success-rate of about 30%. On some devices, it doesn't work at all. There's no problem with 4G connection. It's not fluctuating. It's working fine. I tried this Wi-Fi and mobile data thing on multiple devices. Everything indicates that there's some problem with the code on mobile data.

Currently on my debug device which is on mobile data, the code is working. Hence I can't post logcat now. But many times it doesn't even work on debug device. But right now since it's working, I can't post logcat. Most probably, some problem is in this section of code:

```
 try {
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail", "allrecipients: " + emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

While reading others' thread, I came to know that there may be some problem with Proxy settings. But in the code, I don't know where I can use `Proxy.NoProxy` kind of thing. Full code is available in the above link. I haven't modified that (except adding my own email and password).

Here's the failure logcat:

```
 08-09 19:29:54.594 9551-9551/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/SendMailActivity: Send Button Clicked.
08-09 19:29:54.594 9551-9551/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/SendMailActivity: To List: [cdludeubg@gmail.com]
08-09 19:29:54.654 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/d: About to instantiate GMail...
08-09 19:29:54.668 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: Mail server properties set.

                                                               [ 08-09 19:29:54.677  9551: 9893 W/         ]
                                                               Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
08-09 19:29:55.000 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: toEmail: cdludebug@gmail.com
08-09 19:29:55.099 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: Email Message created.
08-09 19:29:58.393 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/Error: sendEmail: null
08-09 19:29:58.393 9551-9893/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/com.downloadinformer: Mail Sent.
```

**Edit 2**
On another device, I got the logcat as:

```
08-10 17:44:58.911 32384-32384/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/SendMailActivity: Send Button Clicked.
08-10 17:44:58.911 32384-32384/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/SendMailActivity: To List: [cdludeubg@gmail.com]
08-10 17:44:58.922 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/d: About to instantiate GMail...
08-10 17:44:58.930 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: Mail server properties set.
08-10 17:44:59.027 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: toEmail: cdludebug@gmail.com
08-10 17:44:59.088 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/GMail: Email Message created.
08-10 17:44:59.095 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=smtp.gmail.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-10 17:44:59.095 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=smtp.gmail.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-10 17:44:59.208 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: smtp.gmail.com get result from proxy >>
08-10 17:44:59.219 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/System.out: [socket][0] connection smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4003:c00::6c:587;LocalPort=44496(0)
08-10 17:44:59.219 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/System.out: [CDS]connect[smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4003:c00::6c:587] tm:90
08-10 17:45:02.079 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=smtp.gmail.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-10 17:45:02.079 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=smtp.gmail.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-10 17:45:02.083 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: smtp.gmail.com get result from proxy >>
08-10 17:45:02.084 32384-1140/com.parassidhu.cdlumaths I/Error: sendEmail: null
```

Comment: You really need to post the debug output when it fails.  And it would help if you could characterize what's different when it fails vs. when it succeeds.  Are you always using the same mail server with the same user name and password?  Is it always the same device that fails or are you using multiple devices?  Is the failure related to your location?

Comment: Let me try more If i can get the logcat. I am using same mail server. Same username, same password. There are multiple devices on which it fails. This doesn't seem it's related to the location

Comment: Some providers in some countries block ports. Especially on budget phone contracts you sometimes only get http/s ports open. While it is not common today, a few years ago I had similar problems.

Comment: But it was working on the same phone and now suddenly has stopped working. If I make hotspot from a phone to connect that same phone with internet, it works. Can't there be proxy kind of thing? I'm using port 587 for smtp. Isn't there any other way for sending mail instead of smtp?

Comment: Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?

Comment: From where I can obtain that? Logcat?

Comment: Please check Edit 2

Comment: the solution from @Agung worked for me, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42238498/1545993

Comment: @Taifun Thank you for reply. It may help someone although I have implemented server based notifications so no longer needed it

Answer (score 0):

It must be something about the authentication on your mail server. Just using the default android email app, I still can't access my email server over Mobile Data, and its an old server with strange auth. Double check the authentication settings server side.

Comment: That's an alternative method. But I want to make a one-click to send option. Like "Send Thumbs Up". Then User don't want to open email client. There should be one-click send option. Can you check in the code and tell me?

Comment: Sorry, just telling you what I've experienced with this issue, don't really have any more insight...

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, I realize that when I change the preferred network type of the phone from 4G to 3G it works, and then when I change from 3G to 4G it keeps working.

Comment: We can't perform this on each and every user's phone

Answer (score 0):

In my App I solved that, I think it is a problem with smtp.gmail.com.

The solution:

To create a Outlook email and put thease configurations:

- SMTP server name smtp-mail.outlook.com
- SMTP port 587
- SMTP encryption method TLS

  ```
      try {

      String prot = "smtp";
      final String user = "MyEmailAdress@outlook.com";
      String to = "anotherEmail@outlook.com";
      final String pass = "MYpassword";
      String mailhost = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";

      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.put("mail." + prot + ".host", mailhost);
      props.put("mail." + prot + ".auth", "true");
      props.put("mail." + prot + ".starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail." + prot + ".port", "587");
      props.put("mail." + prot + ".ssl.enable", "false");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                      return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                  }
              });
      session.setDebug(true);

      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
              InternetAddress.parse(to, false));

      msg.setSubject("TESTE ENVIO EMAIL");

      msg.setText("Teste de envio de email conteudo");

      msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", user);
      msg.setSentDate(new Date());

      SMTPTransport t =
              (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport(prot);

      t.connect(mailhost, user, pass);

      t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
      t.close();

      Log.d("envio de email", "enviado");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Erro", "actionbt1", e);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my app not sending email via Gmail when connecting via network data, but it worked fine on WiFi.

Google was rejecting the new IP address as suspicious.

Option 1:

To clear the captcha go to this link while signed in to your Google account: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Option 2:

Enable 2-step authentification on your Google account. Then use the following link to generate an application specific password (ASP). Replace your usual gmail password in your code with the ASP.

https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hide_authsub=1

(Select the 'Mail' option in the first dropdown and use the 'Other' option in the second dropdown to insert the name of your app, or any other name you like)