# Javamail Send email work with wifi connection but not with data mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, jakarta-mail, java

I'm new in android. I'm learning about javamail to create app that can send email notification. I follow this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/

It's working well in emulator android. I can receive email. Then I tried to install my app in my android device with Wifi connection, it's working well. But when I use Data Mobile Connection (not Wifi) email not sent. Can you tell me why?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: did you get  any error ? if yes then post it .

Comment: it is common for mobile operator to not allow connections to smtp servers outside of their own.

Comment: The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) will help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @jatDevta : no, I don't get any error, the message notofication is sent in app, but I don't get any email in my inbox or spam folder

Comment: @njzk2 : oh really? any solution?

Comment: @bill-shannon : thanks for the advice, I'll try to debug the output

Comment: #SOLVED 
solution: add this code <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in AndroidManifest.xml file... Thanks all.

Comment: Use an HTTP API located on your a to trigger the email, don't rely on the devices mail server

Answer (score 0):

solution from @Agung from the comments

add this code

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

in AndroidManifest.xml file...